# PHP Script Unable to Execute MATLAB

Tags: php, apache, matlab, xampp, ubuntu-16.04

I have created a Php Script Hosted On (Ubuntu) XAMPP Server http://10.0.68.84/bash/script.php

`<?php 
echo exec('matlab');
?>`

To Run MATLAB IDE through Terminal

Whenever I Run this Address in Browser the MATLAB opens for a Second (Banner Appears) & Get closed Instantly

**Note this PC is Institutional PC With Proxy Networks**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of `PHP` scripts:

```
<?php exec('myapp.exe'); ?>
```

are not intended to be used as application launchers. The [exec function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php), together with other similar function like [passthru](http://php.net/manual/it/function.passthru.php) and [system](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php), are intended to be used when a batch script or a console command need to be executed on the server machine.

If you call run script:

```
<?php exec('notepad.exe'); ?>
```

you are actually opening an instance of Notepad on the server machine, not on the client machine. So the application is sitting there, on the server side, waiting for user input... but the client cannot see it.

You will never bring up a Matlab console like this, but of course you can run single scripts using the following Matlab command line:

```
matlab -nodesktop -nodisplay -nojvm -r "run /path/to/myscript.m"
```

for example:

```
<?php

    $command= '...';
    $output = exec($command);
    echo $output;

?>
```

And you can parametrize your Matlab scripts as much as you want in order to execute complex commands with multiple outputs.